# Unused dict keys when unpacking for string formatting

Tags: python

Is there a way to see which keys from a dictionary were not used when being unpacked for string formatting?

Example:

```py
> format_dict = {'first': 'think', 'second': 'am', 'third': 'never'}

> format_str = 'I {first}, therefore I {second}'

> print(format_str.format(**format_dict))
I think, therefore I am
```

But what I really want to know in this case is that the key `third` is never used. Is there any way to get this information?

Comment: Not without hacking `.format` in someway or another, or manually parsing the template string and compare that to the dict keys

Comment: Why would you need that information?

Comment: @chepner we have a hidden list of usable parameters to be formatted into a sql query template. I want to alert the user that some of their inputs weren't allowed.

Comment: Then wrap the call to `format` in a function that performs your check.

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't be using `str.format` to build SQL queries in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddling with regex isn't necessary here, use official `string.Formatter.parse` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.parse)):

```
import string

format_dict = {'first': 'think', 'second': 'am', 'third': 'never'}
format_str = 'I {first}, therefore I {second}'

format_keys = [i[1] for i in string.Formatter().parse(format_str)]
print(set(format_dict.keys()) - set(format_keys))
```

Prints:

```
{'third'}
```

Comment: Is this way more efficient than the solution with regex posted by DeepSpace?

Comment: @asikorski I would say more correct one, because this is using the same method that `.format()` does. There could be escaped `\{\}` etc...

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the "keys" from the template string then use set operations (set subtraction) to check what keys are in dictionary and not in the template string:

```
import re

format_dict = {'first': 'think', 'second': 'am', 'third': 'never'}
format_str = 'I {first}, therefore I {second}'

not_used = format_dict.keys() - set(re.findall(r'{(.+?)}', format_str))
print(not_used)
```

Outputs

```
{'third'}
```

This can be baked into `.format` by subclassing `UserString`:

```
from collections import UserString
import re

class MyString(UserString):
    def format(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs.keys() - set(re.findall(r'{(.+?)}', str(self))))
        return super().format(*args, **kwargs)

format_str = MyString('I {first}, therefore I {second}')

format_dict = {'first': 'think', 'second': 'am', 'third': 'never'}
print(format_str.format(**format_dict))
```

Outputs

```
{'third'}
I think, therefore I am
```

If you are going to use this a lot then it makes sense to `re.compile` the regex.

Comment: The subclassing you added is a nice method !

Answer (score 1):

You can check the key values from the `dict` against the string before you perform the formatting

```
>>>unused = [v for k,v in format_dict.items() if k not in format_str]
>>>print(unused)
['never']
```

Maybe not so great for collisions, but depends on your strings.